# The right way for creating a custom popup / alert UIView / UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've been developing for iOS for quite a while now, but I always got problems with custom alerts / popups, I just don't know what is the **right** way to add a custom view as a popup on top of all other views in app.

I've checked online and there are several ways to do it, but what is the best way for creating those custom alerts / popups?

There is a `CustomViewController` class and this is how I've created it and add it as a popup:

1. Create a new `UIViewController`
2. Add a `UIView` inside the `UIViewController`'s `XIB` file as a child of `self.view` (This will hold the popup elements inside)
3. Add this method inside the `UIViewController` for presenting the view:

   ```
   - (void)presentViewController
   {
       self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
       self.window.screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

       UIWindow *mainWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
       [mainWindow setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
       [self.window addSubview:self.view];

       self.view.alpha = 0.0f;
       self.backgroundImage.image = [self takeSnapshot];

       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

           self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
           self.view.alpha = 1.0f;

       } completion:nil];
   }
   ```
4. Add this method inside the `UIViewController` for removing the view:

   ```
   - (void)dismissShareViewController
   {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION
                        animations:^{
                            self.view.alpha = 0.0f;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                            self.window = nil;
                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
                            UIWindow *mainWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
                            [mainWindow setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                        }];
   }
   ```

**Usage:**

1. Creating a property for the `UIViewController`

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) CustomViewController *viewController;
   ```
2. Initialize and present

   ```
   - (void)showCustomViewController
   {
       self.viewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
       [self.viewController presentViewController];
   }
   ```

The problem is that I always get a `Received Memory Warning`. Also I've added a `- (void)dealloc` method inside the `CustomViewController` to know if the `UIViewController` is releasing properly, but for some reason the `dealloc` method is getting called right after the `presentViewController` and not after the `dismissShareViewController` as it should.

Another thing that I want to achieve: This `CustomViewController` has no `UIStatusBar` and when I try to present `MFMailComposeViewController`, I always get the `MFMailComposeViewController` to show without a `UIStatusBar` or with white status bar, but I can't change it to default back again. I've tried several question here on `StackOverflow` but without any luck, it just won't change.

[Putting a UIView or UIWindow above Statusbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252053/putting-a-uiview-or-uiwindow-above-statusbar)

Please, for once and for all, someone will help me with it.

Comment: why not use an UIAlertView?

Comment: Because I don't want to use `UIAlertView`, I want something to cover all the screen, but with alpha.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UIAlertView is a subclass of UIView. If you wanted to create a custom alert view, I would also subclass UIView so that it is easy to swap out your existing UIAlertView's with your new custom view.

You can place your custom alert view atop your topmost UIWindow to cover everything.

```
@interface MyAlertView : UIView
- (void)duplicateAllTheFunctionsOfUIAlertViewHere;
@end

@implementation MyAlertView : UIView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRectMake)frame {
  // add your custom subviews here
  // An example of a custom background color:
  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
}

- (void)duplicateAllTheFunctionsOfUIAlertViewHere {
   //re-implement all the functionality in your custom ways
}

- (void)show
{
  UIView* superview = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
  self.frame = superview.bounds;
  [superview addSubview:self];
  // Do an animation if you want to get fancy
}

@end
```

Usage in a view controller:

```
- (void)showAlertView
{
  UIView* alertView = [[MyAlertView alloc] initWithTextAndButtons:@"blah"];
  [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: Please note, this is not recommended. Apple docs does not allow this: "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html

Comment: @dan I didn't subclass uialertview. I subclasses UIView.