# How to add a bar on top of the iphone screen (below status bar)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications

Can someone advise me on how I can implement a "touch to return to call" type of UI as seen in the screenshot below?

[image]

My intention is to display the bar on top when my application receives a notification.

Any guide or resources on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666792/add-uiview-above-all-other-views-including-statusbar

Comment: @Evgeniy Shuarkov thanks for the link. Do you happen to know how I can push the navbar below the overlay? Now the overlay will cover my navbar

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I added an answer with some variants, hope this will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several ways how you can place something below your status bar.
1. You can add `UIView` to `UIWindow` and position it to be under status bar. Set status bar style to black translucent, so the underneath view will be visible. Resize rootViewController appropriately, so it won't overlap your view.
2. Also, you can set `wantsFullScreenLayout` property of your rootViewController to `true`, so it'll cover the entire screen and manage view hierarchy inside it. You also need to set status bar style to black translucent.

Alternatively, you can add views above status bar, but I don't think that this is a good user experience. Here is how you can do that: [Add UIView Above All Other Views, Including StatusBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666792/add-uiview-above-all-other-views-including-statusbar)

Comment: Shuarkov, I want my new view to be between the status bar and navigation bar. The new view that was added will overlap with the navigation bar. Resizing the root view controller (a table in my case) does nothing to adjust the positioning of the navigation bar, resulting in the screenshot in my initial question

Comment: Your rootViewController is UINavigationController (its superview is UIWindow). Your controller with tableView is just the top controller in navigation stack.

Comment: How did you resize the UINavigationController? I'm trying to set the frame using "keyWindow.rootViewController.view.frame" but nothing happens...