# Fixed UIImage PushViewController animated

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, pushviewcontroller

I want to get an image fixed between the animation, so it doesn't move when the app slides to right. A bit like the background of a UINavBar, I couldn't find anyone who tried it earlier so I would really like to know.

Thanks in advance

Sjors

Comment: Why don't you add that image on your window??

Comment: After reading it again, I think my post wasn't clear. I mean iOS, not Mac obj C

Comment: It is clear, the guy is suggesting you use UIWindow. Which is basically the super view of your app. It will be above the animation of your viewControllers.

Comment: oh, I am building storyboard and XIB based, how can I use UIWindow now? Via sb/xib or AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1):

As a response on your last comment, here is how to do this:

```
UIView * hoi = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
hoi.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIWindow * window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[window addSubview:hoi];
```

Alternatively you create add a second UIWindow to which you can add your subviews. As is nicely explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2671148/262691

Comment: Yes, you could put this in the viewDidLoad method of the viewController in which you want to show it at first.

Comment: It does work for me. Alternatively you could create a second UIWindow to attach subviews, I will update my answer